# MongoDB cross-server document update is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, microservices

I'm using microservice architecture where i have multiple servers. in first server i have user schema for users and when I'm trying to update something from different server, but it's not updating anything, and also I'm not getting any error.

```
  //getting users collection without schema and i'm able to read the document with this but not             able to update anything
 `const mongoose = require("mongoose");
 const User = mongoose.model("User", {}, "users");
 module. Exports = User;`
```

i don't know if there any policy for security, or any restriction to update from cross-server connection

i asked ChatGPT, Gemini: say's i can update document, but i don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.